# rsync over SSH sometimes very slow--other times maxes out bandwidth

Tags: bash, ssh, osx, rsync, backup

I have a bash script set up on computer A (Mac OS X) set to run every five minutes via a cronjob. This script checks for new files on remote computer B (Gentoo Linux) then rsyncs any new files to computer A. Sometimes this sync (download) maxes out my connection at 3 MB/s, however sometimes, maybe 10% of the time, it will download at the extremely low rate of 10-50 KB/s. I'm 100% certain this isn't because my Internet connection is dying out/dipping so what could be at fault?

The weird thing is that the rsync jobs that run slow, run slow the ~entire~ time. That is if it is rsyncing a 1 GB file it will sync/download at its extremely slow speed (10-50 KB/s) the entire life of the job until the 1 GB is fully downloaded. This leads me to believe it is not related to CPU load, or networking, but with either the script or something else.

My script is below.

```
# !/bin/sh

# Check if rsync has been timestampped and exit if it has
echo "Checking for local timestamp..." >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
if [ -e /Users/localuser/scripts/.timestamp ]
then
        echo "Local timestamp already exists, exiting..." >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
        exit
fi

# Timestamp rsync
echo "Local timestamp not found, continuing..." >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
touch /Users/localuser/scripts/.timestamp

# Timestamp remote computer B
echo "Timestampping remote computer B" >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
ssh remoteuser@remotecomputerb touch /home/remoteuser/finished/.timestamp

# Run rsync
echo "Starting rsync at $(date)" >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
rsync -avzPL -e ssh remoteuser@remotecomputerb:/home/remoteuser/finished /share --log-file /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log

# Change permissions
echo "Changing permissions" >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
chmod -Rf 775 /share
/usr/sbin/chown -Rf localuser:staff /share

# Delete sym links that are older than the remote computer B timestamp
echo "Deleting sym links on remote computer B" >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
ssh remoteuser@remotecomputerb find /home/remoteuser/finished \! -newer /home/remoteuser/finished/.timestamp -type -l -delete

# Delete the rsync script timestamp
echo "rsync finished at $(date)" >> /Users/localuser/log/rsync.log
rm /Users/localuser/scripts/.timestamp

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be basically anything from link congestion to high CPU usage on the remote computer. In between, all the network devices can also screw up. Especially since you are bombing the ssh port. But buffering problems in the network devices can also be the culprits.

One thing though: next time, double check that rsync is not running twice. Yes, you created workarounds in the script to avoid that, but one never knows... maybe the folder is read-only, maybe the filesystem behaves strangely...

So, you understand it, we don't have enough information to answer correctly.

**However**, I would recommend you to stop using `rsync` for this use case. This is inefficient as well as error prone. Since what you want is folder constant sync, have a look at [syncthings](https://syncthing.net/). It should work better, without lag with the same amount of openness and security. (rsync is great for one-shots and for periodic backups, not for constantly syncing folders)

Comment: I thought rsync was standard for things like this? I will try out Syncthing but I unfortunately don't have full admin access on the remote machine to install things. Some more info about my problem that I'll add to the OP: the weird thing is that the rsyncs that run slow, run slow the ~entire~ time. That is if it is rsyncing a 1 GB file it will sync/download at its extremely slow speed (10-50 KB/s) the entire life of the job until the 1 GB is fully downloaded. This leads me to believe it is not related to CPU load, or networking, but with either the script or something else.

Comment: `rsync` is standard for on-demand backups. It used to be standard for nightly backups but directly requested by the remote computer. With all due respect to both you and `rsync`, the days of `rsync` abuse are over because we have better things (`syncthing` among others, of course!)

Comment: The slow intermittent thing reminds me of a severe buffering problem.

Comment: Can you try to connect to the server with ssh next time it happens, first to check the CPU usage and then, to try direct download (with `scp`).

Comment: You can also ask for more information by using 3 `v` with `rsync`.

Comment: I'll try all that out. Thank you for your time.